# Insert and restore and search in combox?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010, combobox

Salam Alekom .

I have comboBox filling it from database as

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

con.Open();

SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand();
scm.Connection = con;
scm.CommandText = "select * from com";

SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(scm);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adpt.Fill(dt);

comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = dt.Columns["com_name"].ToString();
comboBox1.ValueMember = dt.Columns["com_id"].ToString();
```

Where filling with all data that store in the table from database.

This comboBox use also to insert to another table in database

This also poses no problem

The problem when making search in table to get some data. I need to get the text value that store in table and equal to text value of comboBox and sort it in position 0 of this comboBox

I made the search no problem but what property or method that allow me to put the value in position 0 with out affecting the other values that be in combobox

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
con.Open();

using(SqlCommand scm2 = new SqlCommand())
{
    scm2 .Connection = con;
    scm2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    scm2 .CommandText = "SP_retrieve_data";

    scm2.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@id", textBox1.Text);

    SqlDataReader dr = scm2.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        comboBox1. = dr["com_name"].ToString();//what code accept the value
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!